# Parsing array based on a range and selected index values

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, filter

I have a nested array that has subarrays with a length of 6 and string values. I also have 2 variables that have float values as below:

```
var test_array =[["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
  ["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]];
```

var pt_one = 0.1;
var pt_two = 0.59;
var street = "Fernwood Avenue";

I want to use pt_one and pt_two as a low-high range. I want to iterate through the subarrays and create a new array where subarray[1] is equal to or great than pt_one and subarray[2] is less than or equal to pt_two and subarray[6] = street and push that array to a new_array. For example, the output in this scenario would be:

```
 new_array =[["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"]];
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `filter`, this also checks for `type` number on the comparisons and capitalization/whitespace issues on street.

```js
var test_array = [
  ["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
  ["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]
];



function findIt(low, high, street) {
  return test_array.filter(el =>
    +el[1] >= low && +el[2] <= high && el[6].trim().toLowerCase() === street.trim().toLowerCase());
}


var pt_one = 0.1;
var pt_two = 0.59;
var street = "Fernwood Avenue";

console.log(findIt(pt_one, pt_two, street))
```

Comment: Both excellent solutions. I like that this trims the street name and sets to lowercase. One thing I don't understand (despite that the solution works) is that the low and high values are numbers and the test_array[1] and [2] are string values. I actually ran it using  parseFlot(test_array[1]) ... in the code and it failed, but using it exactly as above, there was no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic filter() operation where you check each of the conditions

```js
var pt_one = 0.1; var pt_two = 0.59; var street = "Fernwood Avenue";

var test_array =[["06101123", "0", "0.2", "34011", "Cumberland", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["02271163", "0.1", "0.22", "34003", "Bergen", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["04351186", "0.3", "0.59", "34007", "Camden", "Local", "Fernwood Avenue"],
  ["07131150", "0", "0.3", "34013", "Essex", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["03041026", "0", "0.13", "34005", "Burlington", "Local", "Beacon Street"],
  ["20121109", "0.18", "0.43", "34039", "Union", "Local", "Jones Lane"],
  ["15141139", "0", "0.27", "34029", "Ocean", "Local", "Jones Lane"]];
  
const res = test_array.filter(arr=>{
   return arr[6] === street && arr[1] >= pt_one && arr[2] <= pt_two;
});

console.log(res)
```